# How to force route users to HTTP

Tags: node.js, express

Just updated our website, and migrated our DNS routing to the new server. The issue we are having now, is sometimes when a user types in our website 'example.com', it will sometimes route them to an `HTTPS://example.com` which isn't currently enabled.

Is there a way to have users routed to our `HTTP://example.com` instead of `HTTPS://example.com`, while we are waiting for SSL to be enabled on the new site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

DNS is for resolving the hostname (`example.com`) to an IP address.  You can't tell the browser to use HTTPS or HTTP via DNS.

I'm assuming that in the past, you've supported HTTPS.  Once you've done that, the browsers often remember.  The best thing to do is get your certificate place ASAP.  You can use Lets Encrypt and Certbot and be done in a couple minutes in most cases.

Comment: Thank you, plan on getting it set up tonight, just wasn't sure if there is something i could do in the interim. But ill just stop being lazy and figure out certbot tonight instead of waiting til tomorrow haha.

Comment: @TheTravelingCoder Even if you just do the manual verification for now, I think you'll find it's pretty easy to use.  You can always get it properly automated later...  just keep in mind that those certificates are only good for 3 months, so you should automate renewals soon, if not tonight.